# Replacing text in div with value in JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a class `.location-header` with text wrapped in a paragraph tag, I need to replace the current value stored in the div with the value stored in the `address` variable. I'm able to replace the value, but the problem is getting it to stay within the `<p></p>` tags for formatting.

```js
var fixed = $('.location-header > p')[0].innerHTML
                              .replace('/(,)(?=\s{1}\D{2}[^\s][^\d{5,}])/g', "<br />");
var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />");

console.log(address);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location-header">
  <p>
    123 Nowhere Ln, Suite 200, Somewhere, NY 10009
  </p>
</div>
```

It needs to replace the text with the plain text with the text that has HTML `<br />` tags. I've tried using `.text`, `.innerHTML`, and `.replaceWith`

The end result should display the address like this:

> 123 Nowhere Ln
>
> Suite 200
>
> Somewhere, NY 10009

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vc4fb8r/)

**UPDATED:**

This is what I get when using `$('.location-header > p').html(address);`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `html()` method like following.

```js
var fixed = $('.location-header > p').text();

var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />") + fixed.substring(fixed.lastIndexOf(','));

$('.location-header > p').html(address);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location-header">
    <p>
        123 Nowhere Ln, Suite 200, Somewhere, NY 10009
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it displays a repeated value instead of just once.

Comment: What do you mean by repeated value? Have you removed `[0]` before `.html()`? @Matt

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I get with `$('.location-header > p').html(address);`

Comment: I think there are multiple `location-header` with `p` in your html. You can use `$('.location-header > p').first()` then or select the correct `p`. @Matt

Comment: Yeah, I need to fix my markup and replace the other `p` tags with `div`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
var fixed = $('.location-header > p')[0].innerHTML.replace('/(,)( =\s{1}\D{2}[^\s][^\d{5,}])/g', "<br />");
var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />");

console.log(address);

$('.location-header > p').html(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first-child` css selector

```js
                 
var fixed = " street name, area, city, pin:000000";
var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />");
var fixed = $('.location-header > p:first-child').html(address.replace('/(,)(?=\s{1}\D{2}[^\s][^\d{5,}])/g', "<br />"));
console.log(address);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location-header">
  <p>
    123 Nowhere Ln, Suite 200, Somewhere, NY 10009
  </p>
</div>
```